# Why does re.match(...) == True print False?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re
print(re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}', '4fdg5Fj3') == True)
```

it is printing `False` but the string given is fullfilling all the conditions of the regular expression.

Comment: Because the result of `re.match` is not equal to `True`.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, given that Python's documentation states, "Match objects always have a boolean value of True." It's not obvious to me the difference between (a) being equal to True and (b) having a boolean value of True. It seems, as highlighted in the accepted answer by @martin-pieters, that [truth-value-testing as True in an if or a while statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) is a special use case for Boolean values, distinct from being equal to True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither a match object nor `None`, the two types of objects that `re.match()` can return, is ever equal to True:

```
>>> importe re
>>> None == True
False
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}', '4fdg5Fj3')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='4fdg5Fj3'>
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}', '4fdg5Fj3') == True
False
```

Don't use `== True`. If you need to see if the match succeeded, test for `is not None`:

```
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}', '4fdg5Fj3') is not None
True
>>> re.match(r'No such pattern', 'will not match') is not None
False
```

You should almost *never* use `== True` or `== False`. In a boolean context like an `if` statement, just drop `== True`; it is the job of the statement to test for the boolean truth. For `== False`, put `not` in front instead. Moreover, as seen above, most objects are not equal to `True` or `False`; to test for the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), just pass in the object itself, or convert the truth value too a boolean using the `bool()` function.

Comment: thanks for the help it's working in my terminal but in this given link https://www.codewars.com/kata/regex-password-validation/train/python/5b0bce166e8f28c1ef000081 if i write above expression it will fails some test don't know why

Comment: That's a different problem from the one in your question. If you have further questions, create a new post.

Comment: And your regex will pass for a password without numbers or uppercase letters, like `fdgfjdoy`, but the requirements are that there should be *at least one* of each of the categories.

Comment: how is it happening why regex is returning true in case of         fdgfjdoy

Comment: @vipinyadav: I already told you: *post a new question*. Comments are not for new questions.